# Has Stefano Di Mera ever been in the Italian Mafia?

Tags: character, days-of-our-lives

In Days of Our Lives Stefano Di Mera is the main arch villain. In my opinion he is the greatest crime boss ever. Has he ever been a member of the Italian Mafia?